# embed custom view into UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I already have a subclass of `UIView`, called `CustomView`, which I use in stack views.

I am wanting to redo the UI and use a table view instead. So, for that I just wanted to reuse the `CustomView` class I already have but for some reason the table view is not showing the cell at all.

I think the issue is the way I am using `CustomView` in `CustomCell: UITableViewCell`:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var customView: CustomView!
}
```

in the view controller holding the table view, I have in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

and

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
  {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
```

When I run the app, I just get a blank table view. 
[image]

Comment: Did you add the custom view to your prototype cell in the storyboard?  Did you set constraints on it?  You don't add any data to it in `cellForRow`, so what should it show?

Comment: You should register the cell class, not the nib: tableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")

Comment: No, if they have a NIB file (which it seems they do since their class has an `IBOutlet`) then registering the NIB is correct.  The NIB needs to refer to the custom cell class and contain a view with its custom class set to `CustomView`

Answer (score 0):

Good day I made the same code that you, and works , could you add breakpoint in this position.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
  {
    return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath)
  }
```

you shouldn't have problem using custom views inside cells.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use designated initializer for your custom view like init(frame:CGRect) or add it to the interface builder, like a prototype cell.